# Unable to Login to WSo2 EMM1.1.0 Admin console after setting up WSO2 EMM 1.10 with External/Public IP - Connection time out Exception

Tags: wso2, wso2-iot

I Configured WSo2 EMM with Public /External IP , As shown below

1) WSo2_EMM_HOME\repository\conf\carbon.xml

```
  Change LocalHost IP to Public IP

  <HostName>125.18.49.46</HostName>
  <MgtHostName>125.18.49.46</MgtHostName>
```

2) WSO2_EMM_HOME\repository\conf\sso-idp-config.xml

```
  Change LocalHost IP to Public IP\

Store
======
<AssertionConsumerService>https://125.18.49.46:9443/store/acs</AssertionConsumerService>

social
======
<AssertionConsumerService>https://125.18.49.46:9443/social/acs</AssertionConsumerService>

publisher
=========
<AssertionConsumerService>https://125.18.49.46:9443/publisher/acs</AssertionConsumerService>

emm
====
<AssertionConsumerService>https://125.18.49.46:9443/publisher/emm/acs</AssertionConsumerService>

mam
====
 <AssertionConsumerService>https://125.18.49.46:9443/mam/acs</AssertionConsumerService>
```

WSo2_EMM_HOME/repository/conf/api-manager.xml

Changed ${carbon.local.ip} to 125.18.49.46

1) https://125.18.49.46:${mgt.transport.https.port}/services/

2) http://125.18.49.46:${http.nio.port},https://${carbon.local.ip}:${https.nio.port}

3)  Added below paramter in (WSo2_EMM_HOME/repository/conf/axis2/axis2.xml )

125.18.49.46

4) In  WSo2_EMM_HOME/repository/conf/identity.xml changed all localhost to 125.18.49.46

Exception :- java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect

Kindly Help out to resolve this issue.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about programming.

Comment: Did you change the configuration from internal wso2 mdm to external mdm connector in app-manager.xml.

Comment: I'm using wso2 emm 1.1.0, i have verified the app-manage.xml in that there is no such <MDMConfig> tag in the xml  to change mdm details, could you please specify where exactly changes needs to be done to point external mdm connector....

Answer (score 1):

Could you able to provide entire back end error log.Because It works for me.

Answer (score 1):

```
java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect
        at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.connect0(Native Method)
        at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.<init>(Unknown Source)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketFactoryImpl.createSocket(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.commons.httpclient.protocol.SSLProtocolSocketFactory.createSocket(SSLProtocolSocketFactory.java:82)
        at org.apache.commons.httpclient.protocol.SSLProtocolSocketFactory.createSocket(SSLProtocolSocketFactory.java:127)
        at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpConnection.open(HttpConnection.java:707)
        at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodDirector.executeWithRetry(HttpMethodDirector.java:387)
        at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodDirector.executeMethod(HttpMethodDirector.java:171)
        at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpClient.executeMethod(HttpClient.java:397)
        at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpClient.executeMethod(HttpClient.java:323)
        at org.wso2.mobile.task.TaskImplementor.execute(TaskImplementor.java:53)
        at org.wso2.carbon.ntask.core.impl.TaskQuartzJobAdapter.execute(TaskQuartzJobAdapter.java:67)
        at org.quartz.core.JobRunShell.run(JobRunShell.java:213)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source)`enter code here`
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: Please move this in to question it self by editing it